# Calculate new tile coordinates for 90 degree rotated square object

Tags: coordinate-systems, rotations

So I have a square (all sides even) with even AxA tiles (for example 3x3). Every tile has its x,y coordinates according its placement. After I rotate the object by 90 degrees around the center, the these world coordinates are no more valid (see image). So what I'm trying to figure out is a formula that takes 3 parameters: 1) old coordinates (x,y), 2) tile count (A) and 3) rotate direction.. and gives new nx,ny after 90 degree rotation. For example 1,1 after rotation becomes 1,3.. 3,2 become 2,1.. 2.2 stays 2.2 and so on. Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: About which point are you rotating? The centre square?

Comment: Yes center. Will add to description. Sorry for leaving that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the rotation matrix centered at $(2,2)$

$\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2\\2\end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta &\cos \theta\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x-2\\y-2\end{bmatrix}$

**EDIT**

To clarify, this is in the sense that anti-clockwise rotations are positive, for clockwise rotations, just put the same angle, but negative.

**EXAMPLE**

$$\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2\\2\end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix}\cos (-90) & -\sin (-90) \\ \sin (-90) &\cos (-90)\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1-2\\1-2\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\implies \begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2\\2\end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1& 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}-1\\-1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}$$

Hence the point (1,1) becomes (1,3) which fits as the above diagram

Comment: Swap $-\sin\theta\leftrightarrow\sin\theta$.

Comment: This is assuming anti-clockwise positive, the standard convention

Comment: Then you should state that the OP has to put $\theta=-90^\circ$.

Comment: How we could make it dynamic? So it takes -90 and 90?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @JanisTaranda It takes any angle, just keep the convention in mind. Btw you should write your attempt to not attract downvotes.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Anyways +1.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan can you calculate one example for me. For example with 1,1. I was not lucky to produced required results.

Comment: But clockwise 1,1 becomes 1,3, not 3,1.. and u said -90 is clockwise

Comment: Ah ok. I tried to use +90, and got also 3,1.. this doesn't seem right.

Comment: Oops, my bad.. typo

Comment: It should be correct now

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan when rotating counter clockwise +90 degree in foruma, 1,1 should become 3,3, but when I do calculations its not the case

Comment: @SameerBaheti it just doesn't work with positive angle - assuming so it goes counter-clock wise.

Comment: I tried with other values. It just doesn't work. Not a solution.

Comment: If you rotate by 180 degrees you'll get (3,3). If you rotate clockwise by 90 you'll get (1,3), which my answer gives

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110970/discussion-between-janis-taranda-and-dhanvi-sreenivasan).